# What lib is typically used (or is there a lib) for making emacs quick-key option views like Magit and Org export?

Tags: emacs, menu, mode

I've been attempting to write a mode that has a quick key for adding links from query a known api.  What I'd like to do is query the rest api for the numbers and summary of items from that api, have the user pick from the list using the keyboard where they are listed next to alpha numeric keys which will then populate the buffer with markdown specific to those links.

I'd like to present the list much like Magit presents the help menu when you press `?` and like org export presents the export menu.  Which typically looks something like this:

```
a  Link Option 1
b  Link 2
c  Some other ID
```

Is there a lib that helps create and manage these kinds of UI components?

Answer (score 2):

[hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) is pretty easy to use:

```cl
(defhydra hydra-links (:exit t
                       :columns 1)
  "sample links"
  ("a" (message "selected Link Option 1") "Link Option 1")
  ("b" (message "selected Link 2") "Link 2")
  ("c" (message "selected Some other ID") "Some other ID"))
```

Comment: Nice!  I'll accept this once I can give it a try.  Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hydras (by abo-abo who answered) are the best option but there are a couple more that are listed here: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Discoverability

The (old) magit library was extracted to get discover.el: https://github.com/mickeynp/discover.el but afaik it's a bit outdated (magit evolved, this library not) and has less features than hydra (an hydra can survive a key press, and that's all the point).